# Mysql syntax error (insert inti) using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

[image]

this how is my table look like, and this is my query

```
query = "insert into archive.exports (DocumentID, from, to, sendDate, dadbox, sonbox, sendBy) values(" + DocumentNum + ", " + from + ", " + to + ", '" + this.date.Value.ToShortDateString() + "', " + DadBox + ", " + SunBox + ", '" + SendBy + "')";
```

it gave me this error
[image]

can someone tell me where is the error, Sorry for my bad english

Comment: `from` and `to` are reserved keywords. you need to escape by wrapping them with backtick. eg. `\`from\`, \`to\``

Comment: @491243 you may want to post that as an answer

Comment: @491243 post that as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from` and `to` are Reserved Keywords and happens to be the name of your column. In order to avoid syntax error, the column name should be escaped using backticks. Ex,

```
INSERT INTO archive.exports (DocumentID, `from`, `to`,...)
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have the privilege to alter the table, change the column name that is not on the *Reserved Keyword List* to prevent the same error from getting back again on the future.